# No output when pushing from R to slack using slackr

Tags: r, slack, slack-api

Tried setting up slackr using the following code:

```
slackr_setup(channel=channel,
incoming_webhook_url="https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx",
api_token = "xxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
username=username)
```

However, when I run the slackr function, there is no output. (There's no error message)

Answer (score 2):

Okay,so I found the reason for this. Didn't want to answer my own question, but it might help someone else having the same issue.

The channel that I was trying to post to was a private channel and once I changed the channel to a public one, it started working.